# Visualize 3d bar and surface plot on same figure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to compare histogram of bivariate random variables with its probability distribution. I have written the code for it and I got both the plots on one figure. But I am not able to distinguish between the two. The bar plot is masking the surface plot.

How can I change colors or any other parameters so that I can visualize them together and compare both plots?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

mu_x = 0
variance_x = 1
mu_y = 0
variance_y = 1
sample=1000

x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal((mu_x, mu_y), [[variance_x, 0], [0, variance_y]], sample).T
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=100, range=[[-10, 10], [-10, 10]],density=True)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25, yedges[:-1] + 0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

x = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X; pos[:, :, 1] = Y
rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[variance_x, 0], [0, variance_y]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the below provided answer any good or helpful?

Comment: This is the only alternative I had identified. I did not get the exact solution to my problem. I want to show that surface would eventually fit the histogram @Bazingaa

Comment: Surface is smooth, histogram is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an offset (you can specify whatever amount you prefer) to the histogram so that both fall on top of each other and then put some transparency to the histogram to see the underlying contour. You can mention in the figure caption that an offset is added for representation purpose. So specifically, you can just use

```
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos+0.35, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
```

which produces

[image]